# Why is my Alexa Skills kit intent timing out

Tags: promise, async-await, alexa-skills-kit

Using the Alexa skills kit node module. I'm trying to make an MQTT call from my handler function using the Alexa skills kit. It seems to send the message correctly, fulfill the promise, but when I test it the actual intent times out. I looked over the code multiple times but cant figure it out.

```js
        const NextPatternIntentHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
                && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'NextPatternIntent';
        },
        async handle(handlerInput) {
            const speakOutput = handlerInput.t('NEXT_MSG');
            const response = await sendMQTT();
            console.log(response);
    
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak("Okay updated the pattern")
                .getResponse();
        }
        };
    
        function sendMQTT() {
        return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
            var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.mqtt-dashboard.com')
            client.on('connect', function () {
                console.log("connected to mqtt server");
                client.subscribe('prancerInTopic', function (err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("subscribed, sending message");
                        client.publish('mytopic', '{"event":"nextpattern"}');
                        resolve("it worked");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                })
            })
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Did you check your Lambda's settings? The default timeout is 3 seconds. Try increasing it to 7 seconds (Alexa timeout at 8 seconds) and see if it helps.

Comment: @Christina I don't think it's actually timing out, it makes it to the  console.log(response); but it never seems actually trigger the  .speak("Okay updated the pattern") statement which has me confused, I pretty much duplicated the pattern used in one of the recipes.